# Произвольный макет поиска

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Помогите пожалуйста реализовать произвольный макет поиска на карте.
Сейчас использую  вне карты и SuggestView, все работает без вопросов.  Попытался создать свой поиск на карте не пойму схему реализации. SuggestView (выпадающая панель подсказок) не работает с инпутом который создаю через templateLayoutFactory.
Любые подсказки, примеры... спасибо!

Comment: Покажите код с которым возникают проблемы

Comment: гуру!!! проверьте, вроде работает, может какие то замечания есть по коду?! Я очень плохо в этом понимаю http://jsfiddle.net/Agapkin/bmk2puvr/2/

Comment: Все нормально. По сути замечаний нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так, может кому пригодится

```
  TemplateSearchCtrl = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    "<div id='searchCtrl'><input type='text' id='map_search'></div>", {
      build: function () {
        TemplateSearchCtrl.superclass.build.call(this);
        this.field = new ymaps.SuggestView('map_search', {
          offset: [0, 10],
          boundedBy: myMap.getBounds()
        });
        this.field.events.add('select', this.FieldSelect, this);
      },
      clear: function () {
        this.field.events.remove('select', this.FieldSelect, this);
        TemplateSearchCtrl.superclass.clear.call(this);
      },
      FieldSelect: function (e) {
        ymaps.geocode(e.get('item').value).then(function (res) {
          myMap.setBounds(res.geoObjects.get(0).properties.get('boundedBy'));
        });
      }
    }),
    SearchCtrl = new ymaps.control.SearchControl({
    options: {
      layout: TemplateSearchCtrl,
      position: {
        top: 10,
        left: 100
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: А какой смысл был вам использовать `templateLayoutFactory` для этого? Вы ведь итак можете назначить `new ymaps.SuggestView('element_id')` без этого?

Comment: @AlexanderKim хххммммм, возможно :-)